# VK CallBack API долгая обработка запроса

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, flask, web-apps

Проблема: есть веб приложение на `Flask`, на которое приходят запросы и он должен на них ответить. Ответ не зависит от запроса, а обработка самого запроса может занимать долгое время.

Вопрос: как вернуть ответ "сразу", а обработку запроса выполнить "на фоне"?

---

Как это реализовано сейчас:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import time
import json
from multiprocessing import Process

app = Flask(__name__)


def event_handler(event):
    time.sleep(300)  # Имитация долгой обработки запроса


@app.route("/callback_server", methods=["POST"])
def vk_callback():
    event = json.loads(request.data)
    if "type" not in event:
        return "Nope"
    if event["type"] == "confirmation" and event["group_id"] == group_id:
        return confirmation_token
    if event["secret"] != secret:
        return "Auth failed"
    proc = Process(target=event_handler, args=(event,))
    proc.daemon = True
    proc.start()
    return "ok"
```

Т.е. сейчас у меня обработка запроса выполняется в отдельном процессе, но я не уверен, что это правильно, т.к. плодить процесс при каждом запросе (а быть их может очень много) это не очень хорошая идея. Если же делать через потоки, то из-за GIL нет гарантии, что ответ вернётся "сразу".

Comment: GIL переключает потоки каждые 5 миллисекунд. Для вас это настолько много?

Comment: @andreymal А если запросов будет много? Ведь возможен же случай, что переключаться будут только потоки обработки запросов, а потоки, возвращающие ответы, будут простаивать?

Comment: Если запросов будет настолько много, что переключение затормозится, то у вас будут намного более серьёзные проблемы помимо GIL :)

Comment: Вообще, если запросов будет настолько много, что какое-то переключение может начать тормозить, то с немаленькой вероятностью переключение процессов в операционной системе будет тормозить точно так же как и GIL)

Comment: @andreymal Я как раз-таки указал в вопросе, что не считаю свое решение хорошим. Вопрос задал, т.к. с веб-разработкой знаком мало и думаю, что для подобной проблемы есть решение, связанное конкретно с веб-разработкой.

Comment: По-настоящему хорошее решение зависит непосредственно от характера необходимой обработки.

Comment: @andreymal Обработка зависит от запроса. Может быть несложный пасинг какого-либо сайта, а может быть факторизация 512-битного числа, к примеру.

Comment: Вообще, если запросов будет не слишком много, то ни с процессами, ни с потоками и GIL проблем не будет. Если запросов будет настолько много, что переключения могут начать тормозить, то процессор не резиновый и ещё задолго до этого момента ваши задачи просто не будут успевать выполняться, и придётся неизбежно распределять их по нескольким компьютерам, и тогда на каждый отдельный компьютер запросов будет опять не слишком много. Так что по-моему вы пытаетесь решать несуществующую проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если проблема в том, что один пользователь при запросе должен дожидаться конца обработки запроса другого пользователя, то тут следует использовать какой-нибудь WSGI (например, [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/). Хостинг pythonanywhere, к примеру, использует uWSGI).

---

Если проблема в том, что **один** пользователь долго ждёт ответа, то возвращать ему ответ до того, как сервер обработал этот запрос, не очень правильно. Контрпример:

- Пусть сущность E создаётся несколько секунд

1. Пользователь отправил запрос на создание какой-либо сущности E;
2. Пользователь сразу же получил ответ, что сущность создана;
3. Следующим запросом пользователь хочет прочитать созданную сущность E, а сервер ещё не успел её создать.

Как это применимо к VK Callback API: [Callback API](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api) имеет механизм повторных отправок уведомлений в случае, если сервер в ответ не вернул `ok`. Проблема кроется в том, что на фоне этот запрос может и не обработаться (завершиться с ошибкой), но сервер вернёт `ok`, что предовратит повторную отправку уведомлений, которая происходит при неудаче. **Таким образом, Ваш "фоновый процесс" запрос не обработает, но сервер ответит что обработал**.

Если же это не является проблемой и всё ещё остаётся необходимость обрабатывать запросы "в фоне", то лучше обрабатывать их в процессах, а не потоках, т.к., судя по описанию, обработка запроса здесь является CPU-bound операцией. Только вместо того, чтобы плодить процесс при каждом запросе, лучше завести некий пул процессов и отправлять задачу им. Таким образом, всегда будет крутиться фиксированное количество процессов, которые будут выполнять задачи из очереди.